# How to make .php files work in microsoft sharepoint?

Tags: php, sharepoint

Hi I just uploaded some .php files to my sharepoint site. But when I go to these pages, instead of showing the page, it is showing the actual script.How can I sovlve this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint runs on top of Microsoft IIS and ASP.NET and does NOT include a PHP engine. A PHP file is just a text file in the eyes of SharePoint. You can configure the IIS with a PHP engine but it will have nothing to do with SharePoint whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

I would not install the PHP engine within SharePoint, with SharePoint configuring being so mixed around I like to keep SharePoint to itself.  Instead install in for its own web site then use the Page View to have it displayed on the SharePoint Page.